# Отслеживание коллизий SurfaceView

Tags: android

Интересует такой вопрос, пишу кликер на SurfaceView.У меня есть обьект и мне нужно отследить коллизию с другим обьектом. Знаю что можно сравнивать вершины обьекта или рисовать Rect и через метод intersect(Второй рект) отследить.Но что делать если один из обьектов повернут, как в таком случае отследить коллизию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с API 19 доступен метод `op` для анализа пересечения объектов `Path`, но он относительно медленный.
Идея проста: создать главный объект игры как экземпляр класса `Path`, а затем проверять на пересечение с объектами игрового мира такими же объектами `Path`. Для ускорения процесса, игровые объекты, которые явно не попадают даже в описанный прямоугольник игрового объекта можно отбрасывать сразу. Path позволяет создавать сложные кривые, смотрите по [ссылке](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path).

```
Path path_for_test = new Path();
if( path_for_test.op( path_main, path_game_object, android.graphics.Path.Op.INTERSECT) ){
    //collision is detected
    //можно использовать метод и с двумя параметрами
}
```

Comment: а в него можно как то встроить image?

Comment: @Dranik можно представить спрайт как прямоугольник, используйте команды "рисования" по точкам moveTo lineTo lineTo lineTo close

Comment: Затупил что -то) Спасибо огромное)

Comment: Вы не подскажете почему при вызове этого метода он всегда возвращает true?

Comment: @Dranik Не должен, проверьте координаты, попробуйте потестировать на простых прямоугольниках

Comment: Path path_for_test = new Path(); не надо ничего задавать?

Comment: Я даже нарисовал эти пути но все равно даже визуально в другую сторону летит а все равно вызываеться

Comment: @Dranik а попробуйте полученный путь проверить на "пустоту" isEmpty